# Convert Json format to xml format

Tags: xml, json, vb.net, json.net

I have the query to select data:

```
Public Function GetStaffList(StaffCode As String) As IEnumerable
   Dim query = (From c In Staff Where c.StaffID= StaffCode Select c)
   Return query
End Function
```

After that I using code below to return Json:

```
Public Function GetPersonListJson(PersonCode As String) As String 
   Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStaffList(StaffCode))
End Function
```

The Json format as below:

```
"[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"PersonID\":10001.0,\"PersonName\":\"Staff1\"}]"
```

If I want to return as XML format, how do I do? Thanks

**UPDATE:** I try using the following code to return xml

```
   Public Function GetPersonListJson(PersonCode As String) As String 
       Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStaffList(StaffCode))
       Dim rootJson = "{""root"":" & json & "}"
       Dim xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(rootJson)
       Return xml.ToString()
    End Function
```

The value of xml during debug is:

```
<root xmlns:json="http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json" json:id="1"><PersonID>10001</PersonID><PersonName>Staff1</PersonName> <EntityKey json:id="2"><EntitySetName>tblPerson</EntitySetName><EntityContainerName>PersonEntities</EntityContainerName><EntityKeyValues><Key>PersonID</Key><Type>System.Decimal</Type><Value>10001</Value></EntityKeyValues></EntityKey></root>
```

After added .ToString(), the return result as following:

```
"\u000d\u000a \u000d\u000a 10001<\/PersonID>\u000d\u000a Staff1<\/PersonName>\u000d\u000a \u000d\u000a
```

But this is not xml format. Please help again. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`DeserializeXNode` method](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXNode.htm). Based on your JSON you'll likely need to specify a root element name for the XML element. Below I've used "Staff" as the root name.

```
Dim xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Staff")
```

The above returns an `XDocument`. To return the XML as a string, add `.ToString()` at the end of it. Based on your comments it sounds like you're trying to add this code to your existing `GetPersonListJson` method. So you could add this line after the one above:

```
Return xml.ToString()
```

That said, your method name no longer matches what you're actually doing. It's named `GetPersonListJson` but now you're returning XML as a string, not JSON. I would suggest renaming it for clarity.

**UPDATE:** your sample string is a json array, which is why the above gives you the `XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object` error. To fix this you'll need to add a root element to your JSON manually:

```
Public Function GetPersonListJson(PersonCode As String) As String 
   Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStaffList(StaffCode))

   ' this step adds a root to the json (you can rename "root" to anything)'
   Dim rootJson = "{""root"":" & json & "}"

   Dim xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(rootJson)
   Return xml.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: Are you mean my code should be like this? JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStaffList(StaffCode)),"Staff")?

Comment: @HowardHee yes, I meant that `json` in my code is the result of the `GetPersonListJson` method, which is what you've shown in the comment.

Comment: Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStaffList(StaffCode))   
Dim xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Staff")
            Return xml   I write the following code,but get error message: "System.Xml.Linq.XDocument cannot be converted to String"

Comment: @HowardHee I've updated my post with some additional details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but when I execute the program,hit exception "XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object."

Comment: @HowardHee please see the update I added to my answer. My original answer applies to a regular Json object. Since you have a Json *array* you need to wrap it with a Json root before deserializing.

Comment: I was updated my question, please help again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work:

```
    string xml = "";
    string json = @"{
                    '?xml': {
                      '@version': '1.0',
                      '@standalone': 'no'
                    },
                    'root': {
                    'object': " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.None)
                    + "}}";
    var xd = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
    using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
      using (var xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sw)) {
        xd.WriteTo(xw);
        xw.Flush();
        xml = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
      }
    }
```

Credit to this page: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may run into in using DeserializeXmlNode is that it will convert long decimals to scientific notation

For example:

```
{
  "imp_currency_exchange": [{
      "base_currency_code": "USD",
      "exchange_currency_code": "IDR",
      "exchange_date": "2022-02-01T16:06:50Z",
      "exchange_rate": 14205,
      "batch_id": "FXR-20220201_3",
      "reverse_exchange_rate": 0.0000703977
    }
  ]
}
```

converts to

```
<root>
  <imp_currency_exchange>
    <base_currency_code>USD</base_currency_code>
    <exchange_currency_code>IDR</exchange_currency_code>
    <exchange_date>2022-02-01T16:06:50Z</exchange_date>
    <exchange_rate>14205</exchange_rate>
    <batch_id>FXR-20220201_4</batch_id>
    <reverse_exchange_rate>7.03977E-05</reverse_exchange_rate>
  </imp_currency_exchange>
</root>
```

which is kinda problematic  (at least for me).  there's no DeserializeXNode that allows you to pass in settings, so you kinda have to dig into the source code to see what DeserializeXNode is doing, then do it better.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs

Like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;

XmlNodeConverter xmlConverter = new XmlNodeConverter();
xmlConverter.DeserializeRootElementName = "root";
xmlConverter.WriteArrayAttribute = false;
xmlConverter.EncodeSpecialCharacters = false;
settings.Converters.Add(xmlConverter);

string myXML = (XDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(XDocument), settings).ToString();
```

Hope this helps someone, it took me hours to dig through and figure this one out.

oh and sorry if the code doesn't actually work, i'm working in VB and converted it for y'all so there's no snubbing of the noses, i didn't feel like testing it :)